# ORDERBY timestamp performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, order-by, geometry

I have some queries dealing with coordinates stored in `POINT`.
Everything is ok without order (about 0.6 ms to query a 5 millions posts and 1 million users database, for testing) but go to 13s when add `ORDER BY created_at DESC`.)

All fields in `WHERE` clauses have index.
`Created_at` index is DESC sort.

Deal is to recover Posts submitted by Users in Geographical Sphere.

```
SET @radius = 30;

SET @center = GeomFromText('POINT(12.005 -1.001)');
SET @r = @radius/69.1;
SET @bbox = CONCAT('POLYGON((', 
  X(@center) - @r, ' ', Y(@center) - @r, ',', 
  X(@center) + @r, ' ', Y(@center) - @r, ',', 
  X(@center) + @r, ' ', Y(@center) + @r, ',', 
  X(@center) - @r, ' ', Y(@center) + @r, ',', 
  X(@center) - @r, ' ', Y(@center) - @r, '))' 
);

SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE posts.user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id  FROM users_contact WHERE
    Intersects( coordinates, GeomFromText(@bbox) ) 
    AND SQRT(POW( ABS( X(coordinates) - X(@center)), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(coordinates) - Y(@center)), 2 )) < @r )
    AND users.user_status=1 AND posts.status=1 AND posts.created_at <= '2016-10-24 10:30:53' AND posts.context = '1'
# ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 30;
```

Tried `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN` Clause, but result is the same.
Putting Coordinates in users table instead of users_contact is the same.

Thanks, `MySQL 5.5`

Answer (score 2):

This is normal situation

- when You run query without ORDER BY - LIMIT 30; work perfect - it stop query after first 30 records, any 30 records
- When You add ORDER BY - MySQL first send all records to temporary table (if dataset big), than sort it, and then return to You 30 correct records

So on huge dataset - it work as expected.
Solution really only one - analyse query and reduce number of total records returned by query, how - depend from business logic

For example - posts.created_at <= '2016-10-24 10:30:53' (it mean yesterday) return all records from 5 000 000, but if add posts.created_at >= '2016-09-24 10:30:53' it return only month of data and etc - any legal ways for reduce number of records.

Second recommendation depend from Your table structure, some time replace SELECT * to the SELECT "WHAT REALLY NEED" could dramatically increase speed - for example one of column BLOB or TEXT, so exclude this column from SELECT - reduce size of data before sort for many. many times.
Even if this BLOB column need for You - You can request it by ID (single record) by second query from the page

Comment: Yes, agree with you of course for best delimitation of the created_at clause.

Comment: ... so doing some tests with about 150 000 new posts by days, to paginate, it seems not relevant to use someting like ORDER BY... and then LIMIT X,Z.

Comment: ... better performance with doing first a count of possibly context (ex. hour per hour) and then get both timestamp limit to do a simple ORDER BY LIMIT Z. Constraint : have to do a loop on count to reach the necessary number. Not really pretty for me.

Answer (score 2):

OK found the real problem.
After optimizing where clauses, escaping some datas in the select, problem was the same.

In fact, in my large post table, i've got a context column with very low cardinality (about 7 for 5 Millions of records.) So of course, index in this column is never used. So queries are ok without a where clause on this column and awfull with.

Will open another question for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may get more traction from this 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(context, status, created_at)
```

`INDEX(...created_at DESC)` -- the `DESC` is ignored.  (That is, until 8.0.)  However the 3-column index I suggest will still 'work' because the first two parts are `=`, then it will scan the index in reverse order.

You could *try* adding `FORCE INDEX`, but that is often a bad idea in the long run.

The problem with the Optimizer's view of your query is that it can't tell whether to start with `user_id` or `created_at`.  If it starts with `user_id`, it might be doing a lot of computing, only to throw it away.  If it starts with `created_at`, it may have to scan through lots of rows to find a nearby user.  That is probably what happened with your 13s.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to get more clues.

Another thing that is somewhat useful is a "bounding box".  This is where you add something like this in order to limit the choices some:

```
 AND latitude  BETWEEN ... AND ...
 AND longitude BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

and have `INDEX(latitude)`.  (It's useless to include both in the index.)